# Error Hydration failed with react-speech-recognition

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I wanted to try speech recognition in NextJS 13. I installed [react-speech-recognition](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-speech-recognition) and copy/pasted the provided example. But I am getting `Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.`

I tried to rollback react to `v18.1`, removed `.next` folder but it didn't help. I scrolled NextJS documentation about [React Hydration Error](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/react-hydration-error), but I don't call `windows` and don't put `div` tag in `p`.

Any ideas what can be the issue?

Code:

```
'use client'
import 'regenerator-runtime/runtime'
import React from 'react'
import SpeechRecognition, {
  useSpeechRecognition,
} from 'react-speech-recognition'

export default function page() {
  const {
    transcript,
    listening,
    resetTranscript,
    browserSupportsSpeechRecognition,
  } = useSpeechRecognition()

  if (!browserSupportsSpeechRecognition) {
    return <span>Browser doesn't support speech recognition.</span>
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Microphone: {listening ? 'on' : 'off'}</p>
      <button onClick={SpeechRecognition.startListening}>Start</button>
      <button onClick={SpeechRecognition.stopListening}>Stop</button>
      <button onClick={resetTranscript}>Reset</button>
      <p>{transcript}</p>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hydration error is caused by these lines:

```
  if (!browserSupportsSpeechRecognition) {
    return <span>Browser doesn't support speech recognition.</span>
  }
```

Because you are using the `'use client'` directive, this component behaves as traditional page components on previous Next.js versions (The page is pre-rendered and then sent to the client to be hydrated). The library you are using checks if `webkitSpeechRecognition` or `SpeechRecognition` exists in the `window` object in order to set the `browserSupportsSpeechRecognition` boolean, but `window` is not available server-side (it is `undefined`). The condition above evaluates to `true` thus creating the mismatch between what was rendered on the server and on the client-side's first render (You can view the page's source and you will notice that the **not supported text** was rendered on the server).

You can solve the issue using `useState` and `useEffect` hooks, taking advantage of the fact that `useEffect` only runs on the client-side:

```
'use client'

import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import 'regenerator-runtime/runtime'
import SpeechRecognition, {
    useSpeechRecognition
} from 'react-speech-recognition'

const Page = () => {
  const [speechRecognitionSupported, setSpeechRecognitionSupported] =
    useState(null) // null or boolean

  const {
    transcript,
    listening,
    resetTranscript,
    browserSupportsSpeechRecognition
  } = useSpeechRecognition()

  useEffect(() => {
    // sets to true or false after component has been mounted
    setSpeechRecognitionSupported(browserSupportsSpeechRecognition) 
  }, [browserSupportsSpeechRecognition])

  if (speechRecognitionSupported === null) return null // return null on first render, can be a loading indicator

  if (!speechRecognitionSupported) {
    return <span>Browser does not support speech recognition.</span>
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Microphone: {listening ? 'on' : 'off'}</p>
      <button onClick={SpeechRecognition.startListening}>Start</button>
      <button onClick={SpeechRecognition.stopListening}>Stop</button>
      <button onClick={resetTranscript}>Reset</button>
      <p>{transcript}</p>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Page
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but I think checking for server rendering (when the window object is undefined) is a little bit less messy solution:

```
  const isServer = typeof window === "undefined";
  if (!browserSupportsSpeechRecognition && !isServer) {
    return <div>Your browser does not support speech recognition.</div>;
  }
```

Works well!